# How do I get the for loops working for searching in a txt file?

Tags: c++

I have been working on  this code for a while now but I can't seem to get this for loop working:

```
if (name != "n")
{
    for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
    {
        if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a code to search for text in a file and I tried running this syntax in other projects too but it doesn't work at all.
Here's some more of the code:

```
bool search() // The search option to search in the txt file
{
    string choi;
    string line;
    bool mainFlag = false;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

reSrch:

    string name = "n";
    string star = "n";
    int year = 0;

    string blunt = "n";
    string blunt2 = "n";
    int blunt3 = 0;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << "\n Please enter the name of the Movie (or n to skip name) : ";
    cin >> blunt;
    if (blunt != "n")
        name = blunt;

    cout << "\n Please enter a name of any one star of the Movie (or n to skip name of star) : ";
    cin >> blunt2;
    if (blunt2 != "n")
        star = blunt;

    cout << "\n Please enter the year of production of the Movie (or 0 to skip year) : ";
    cin >> blunt3;
    if (blunt3 != 0)
        year = blunt3;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (blunt == "n" && blunt2 == "n" && blunt3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n You have not entered any of the information to make a search. Would you\n like to try again? If not then you will be sent back to the main menu."
            "\n\n Please enter yes or no : ";
        cin >> choi;

        if (choi == "YES" || choi == "Yes" || choi == "yes")
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            goto reSrch;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            mainFlag = true;
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    else
    {
        mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);

        if (name != "n")
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
            {
                if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (star != "n")
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
            {
                if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (year != 0)
        {
            string year_string = to_string(year);
            for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
            {
                if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        mov.close();
    }

    return mainFlag;
}
```

This part is in a bool function that return the user's choice if he wanted to go through again the whole entry are or anything. There is a problem somewhere within this function and not outside but If in comments then of course I surely will provide. And this is my second time making a project on file handeling so I don't know much. **I did some editing before moving the code to another project and before that I remember it working just fine**.
**EDIT:** **The code stops when it reaches the for loop. It closes the compiling. no error.** ok so here is the full code anyways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

fstream mov, mov2;

void demo();
int menu();
bool search();
void addMR();



int main()
{

reMain:

    switch (menu())
    {
    case 1:
        if (search() == true){ goto reMain; }
        else{ break; }
    case 2:
        addMR(); break;
    case 3:
        delMR(); break;
    case 4:
        break;
    case 5:
        break;
    case 6:
        break;
    case 7:
        demo(); goto reMain;
    default:
        cout << "\n  Please enter a valid option!";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("CLS");
        goto  reMain;
    }

    string line;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}



//////////////////// - FIN
int menu() // The main menu prompt options to the user
{
    int choice;
    cout << "\n Please choose any of the options given below :"
        "\n ======================================================================================================================\n"
        "\n 1. search for a movie"
        "\n\n 2. add a new movie record"
        "\n\n 3. delete a movie record"
        "\n\n 4. edit existing movie record"
        "\n\n 5. change availability status"
        "\n\n 6. check availability"
        "\n\n 7. Add demo information for program testing\n\n"
        "\n\n Your choice : ";
    cin >> choice;

    Sleep(2000);
    system("CLS");

    return choice;
}
//////////////////// - FIN
void demo() // A function to add demo values to test program functionality
{
    string line2 = "name alien\n"
        "year 1979\n"
        "stars yaphet-kotto\n"
        "stars sigourney-weaver\n"
        "totalNoOfCopies 2\n"
        "noOfCopiesRentedOut 1\n"

        "\nname repo-man\n"
        "Year 2020\n"
        "stars harry-dean-stanton\n"
        "totalNoOfCopies 4\n"
        "noOfCopiesRentedOut 2\n"

        "\nname midnight-run\n"
        "year 2011\n"
        "stars yaphet-kotto\n"
        "totalNoOfCopies 1\n"
        "noOfCopiesRentedOut 1\n\n";

    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);

    mov << line2;

    mov.close();


    system("CLS");

    cout << "\n Demo information has been added to the file!";

    Sleep(4000);
    system("CLS");
}

bool search() // The search option to search in the txt file
{
    string choi;
    string line;
    bool mainFlag = false;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

reSrch:

    string name = "n";
    string star = "n";
    int year = 0;

    int file_line_number = 0;
    string blunt = "n";
    string blunt2 = "n";
    int blunt3 = 0;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    cout << "\n Please enter the name of the Movie (or n to skip name) : ";
    cin >> blunt;
    if (blunt != "n")
        name = blunt;

    cout << "\n Please enter a name of any one star of the Movie (or n to skip name of star) : ";
    cin >> blunt2;
    if (blunt2 != "n")
        name = blunt;

    cout << "\n Please enter the year of production of the Movie (or 0 to skip year) : ";
    cin >> blunt3;
    if (blunt3 != 0)
        year = blunt3;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (blunt == "n" && blunt2 == "n" && blunt3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "\n You have not entered any of the information to make a search. Would you\n like to try again? If not then you will be sent back to the main menu."
            "\n\n Please enter yes or no : ";
        cin >> choi;

        if (choi == "YES" || choi == "Yes" || choi == "yes")
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            goto reSrch;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(1500);
            system("CLS");
            mainFlag = true;
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    else
    {
        mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);

        if (name != "n")
        {
            while (std::getline(mov, line))
            {
                ++file_line_number;
                if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    std::cout << "\n"
                        << "Found it!\n"
                        << "In line no# " << file_line_number << std::endl;
                    break;  // ??? So, what does this do?????
                }
            }
        }
        else if (star != "n")
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
            {
                if (line.find(star, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (year != 0)
        {
            string year_string = to_string(year);
            for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)
            {
                if (line.find(year, 0) != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        mov.close();
    }

    return mainFlag;
}

///////////////////// - FIN
void addMR() // The option to add a movie in the record
{
    string name;
    cout << "\n Enter the name of the movie : "; cin >> name;
    int year;
    cout << "\n Enter the production year of the movie : "; cin >> year;
    string star;
    cout << "\n Enter names of the stars (e.g. starA-starB) : "; cin >> star;
    int copiesAvl;
    cout << "\n Enter total number of copies available : "; cin >> copiesAvl;
    int copiesRnt;
    cout << "\n Enter number of copies rented out : "; cin >> copiesRnt;

    string line3;

    mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);

    mov << "\n\nname " << name
        << "\nyear " << year
        << "\nstars " << star
        << "\ntotalNoOfCopies " << copiesAvl
        << "\nnoOfCopiesRentedOut " << copiesRnt;

    mov.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: Usually, a `for` loop is for a known number of iterations (loops).  A `while` loop is for unknown number of iterations.  Most file reading uses a `while` loop.

Comment: BTW, if you find the line in the file, you keep reading.  You may want to use `break` to exit the `for` loop when you find the item.

Comment: Your [algorithm](https://godbolt.org/z/KZbxGN) for finding a certain name on a line seems to be fine though (linked example).

Comment: @cigien, sorry I forgot that but I added that to the post as well. It doesnt run any further. Gives no error. I mean it reaches the end somehow in main by skipping it.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but should the second `name = blunt` be `star = blunt2`?  Also, make your code to search for a match into a function (to avoid duplicating that code).

Comment: You should `transform` your input string to all lower case or all upper case before comparing.  This will limit your compares to one.  See `std::transform, std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.

Comment: IMHO, you should convert the `goto` to a `while` or `do { } while` loop.  The `goto` statement can lead to *spaghetti code*.

Comment: Since your code "closes compiling", please update your post with the compiler error messages, as text, verbatim.  You may want to understand the difference between compiling code and running the code.

Comment: The thing you aren't doing, which you should **always** do, is check that you successfully opened the file. If the file isn't open that would explain why you never get into your for loop. It only takes a minute to add some quick code to check the a file opens successfully, and it can save you hours of head scratching.

Comment: Re: The use of a `for` loop in `for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(mov, line); i++)` - I think that's perfectly fine. It keeps the scope of `i` tight and doesn't clutter the body of the loop with a `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to switch to a `while` loop:

```
int file_line_number = 0;
while (std::getline(mov, line))
{
    ++file_line_number;
    if (line.find(name, 0) != string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "\n"
                  << "Found it!\n"
                  << "In line no# " << file_line_number << std::endl;
        break;  // ??? So, what does this do?????
    }
}
```

The above code fragment reads lines until EOF.
If the line is found, the loop ends with the `break` statement.

Comment: Hi, man this code looks alright and I think the previous one was too but the problem is somewhere else. I edited the post and posted the whole code there too, it's not too long. I used these lines too which you provided and I'm really greatful for that, I will surely use these but the previous problem still remain. I use visual studio and this function was in a switch/case statement. Where the loop is supposed to give its output, It just says "Press any key to continue".

Answer (score 0):

You aren't opening your file correctly

```
mov.open("movie.txt", ios::app);
```

This opens the file for writing not reading.

Try this to open the file for input

```
mov.open("movie.txt", ios::in);
```

Some advice to avoid this problem in the future. Declare file variables in the functions that need them, not globally. This also has the advantage that you don't have to remember to close the file because it will be closed automatically when the function exits. Use `ifstream` for functions which need to read data, and `ofstream` for functions which need to write data, only use `fstream` for the rare occaisions where you want to read and write at the same time.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Changing to ios::in worked but for only the first IF but the same problem still presists with the other two ELSE IF below that one.

Comment: @SaifAliJT I can't explain that, are you sure you have that right?

Comment: yes. I tried looking for other possible errors but I couldnt find any, there were one or two but even after fixing those I was unable to get it to work for the other two. It's definitely a mior one I just can't find it because I'm not very good at this yet

Comment: @SaifAliJT I expect the reason the other two cases aren't working is for some other reason. This kind of problem is what programmers use a debugger for. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: I use Visual Studio so yeah I do know about the windows local debugger being there but I dont know what it does nor have I ever used it.

Comment: @SaifAliJT Well it would take too long to explain here but you should really learn how to use it, maybe there's an online tutorial. Basically it allows you to run your program one line at a time, and to examine all the variables as you go. So you can see exactly where your program goes and what calculations it is making. It's the number one productivity tool a programmer has. And as debuggers go, the Visual Studio one is the best.